# Работа с датой в JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, postgresql

**Помогите понять как работать с датой в JS.

Ситуация:**
Есть 
    `<input type="date" ng-model="date">`
который при вводе значения 14.12.2016 отдает дату в формате `"2016-12-14T21:00:00.000Z"`, при отправке этой даты на сервер, в базу помещается значение (поле Postgres типа date) 14.12.2016. Но обратно из базы данные уже прилетает `"2016-12-13T21:00:00.000Z"`, т.е. на один день меньше, либо больше в зависимости от выбранного часового пояса на клиенте. 
**Вопрос:** какие надо производить манипуляции с этими данными чтобы выбрав на клиенте 14.12.2016, и сохранив это значение в базу получить на любом клиенте в любом часовом поясе эту же дату.

Comment: В часовом поясе +3, если в 
<input type="date"> введено 15.12.2016 то значение равно "2016-12-14T21:00:00.000Z", т.е. уже на один день меньше.

Comment: Вводите дату как текст, и проверяйте её regex (как по-старому).

Comment: А дата у вас по UTC формату летает ? Насколько мне известно, если представить обработку в UTC и на сервере и на клиенет, при этом учитывать часовой пояс только на клиенте (т.е. на серваке всегда время UTC, а на клиенте в зависимости от выбранных настроек) то должно сработать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил использовав библиотеку [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Написал такую функцию на клиенте после отправки на сервер (JS) и на сервере перед отправкой на клиент (Node.js):

```
$scope.fixDate = function(value) {
    return moment(value).format("DD.MM.YYYY");
};
```

Она переводит дату такого формата:

```
"2016-12-14T21:00:00.000Z"
```

в такую:

```
"15.12.2016"
```

И вроде-бы независимо от часового пояса дата возращается одна и та же.